# Show $A^T U A=0$ iff $A=0$ when $U$ is positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing, matrix-analysis

Let $U$ a symmetric,positive definite matrix. It's known that $A^T UA$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. My goal is to show that

> $A^T U A =0$ iff $A=0$

The $\Longleftarrow$ implication is trivial.

The $\Longrightarrow$ is tricky to me: I'll try to show it by contradiction: suppose $A \ne 0$. Then, given a non-zero $v$ we have $Av = w \ne 0$

This implies that $v^TA^TUAv =w^TUw >0$ since U is S.P.D. How can I conclude that the **whole matrix** $A^T U A\ne 0$ ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of "S.P.D."?  Is the zero matrix SPD?

Comment: The condition that $U$ is PSD, i.e. $\forall x:x^\top U x \geq 0 \iff A\succeq 0$ is not enough. For then there may be a column of $A$, such that $0 \neq a_i \in \ker U$. On the other hand, if $U\succ 0$, then $x^\top U x > 0$ for all nonzero $x$, so this implies that the columns of $A$ must be zero.

Comment: Note that the diagonal entries of $A^TUA$ have the form $x^TUx$ where $x$ is a column of $A$.

Comment: $A^TUA = \mathbf 0  \iff \Big\Vert U^\frac{1}{2}A\Big \Vert_F = 0 \iff U^\frac{1}{2}A = \mathbf 0\implies A=\mathbf 0$ because positive definiteness implies $U^\frac{1}{2}$ is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to consider the contrapositive. If $A^TUA=0$, then $x^TA^TUAx$ is identically zero. Since $U$ is positive definite, we obtain $Ax=0$. But $x$ is arbitrary. Hence $A$ must be zero.

Comment: I don't get this part: "Since $U$ is positive definite, we obtain $Ax=0.$ But $x$ is arbitrary. Hence $A$ must be zero."

Why if U is positive definite you have $Ax =0$? @user1551

Comment: @Vefhug By definition, since $U$ is PD, we have $v^TUv>0$ whenever $v\ne0$. Now put $v=Ax$.